# Como hago para pasar el valor recibido en el textarea a innerHTML para que me tome las etiquetas

Tags: javascript

Tengo un código donde estoy haciendo un sistema de comentarios donde el objetivo es que publiquen
problemas y resoluciones de un Bootcamp de JavaScript para principiantes.

Reemplace el input por un `textarea` para que puedan entrar obviamente mucho mas texto y sea legible a la hora de realizar el comentario o nuevo mensaje.

En el código lo que hago es hacer un función donde presionando la tecla `Enter` y que el valor actual sea distinto a '' (un string vacío), se mande el comentario. Me base en el método de `keydown`, porque uno de mis problemas es que no sabría como implementar otro método que no sea
`keydown`, por ejemplo `keyup`, que es el que me serviría.

Ahora, el siguiente código se me ejecuta apenas yo apretó `enter`, no me deja realizar un salto de línea, con `shift` `enter` o simplemente `enter`.

y me devuelve el comentario, todo seguido en una sola línea sin respetar los saltos de líneas.

Quisiera convertir los `/n` en `<br>` pero tampoco le encuentro la vuelta.
Intenté de varias maneras y todavía no le encuentro el caso.

Podría implementar un botón de posteo, pero cuando intento crearlo se me borra el `textarea` de la pagina y no se porque, si siguiendo el bloque debería mostrarlo.

Cuando lo hago, el botón me queda fuera del `textarea` y se me complica emparejarlo para que quede prolijo.

En cuestión, quisiera que me digan como puedo hacer para que me devuelva la cadena de string con los saltos de líneas correspondientes.

---

En el código van a observar las variables que declaro.
como las relaciono.
Cuando creo una evento.
Creo la funcion para la tecla.
la estructura para que se devuelvan los comentarios y respuestas.
Le agrego 2 botones, de like y de respuesta.

```js
const comments = []
const input = document.getElementById('idTextarea');
const placeHolder = input.placeholder = "  Nuevo mensaje...";

const inputContainer = document.getElementById('inputContainer')
const commentContainer = document.querySelector('#comments-container')

input.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  handleEnter(e, null);
})

commentContainer.appendChild(inputContainer);
inputContainer.appendChild(input);

function handleEnter(e, current) {

  if (e.key === 'Enter' && e.target.value !== '') {
    const newComment = {
      text: e.target.value,
      likes: 0,
      responses: []
    }
    if (current === null) {
      comments.unshift(newComment);
    } else {
      current.responses.unshift(newComment);
    }
    e.target.value = '';
    commentContainer.innerHTML = '';
    commentContainer.appendChild(inputContainer);

    console.log(comments);
    renderComments(comments, commentContainer)
  }
}

function renderComments(arr, parent) {
  arr.forEach(element => {
    const commentContainer = document.createElement('div')
    commentContainer.classList.add('comment-container');

    const responsesContainer = document.createElement('div')
    responsesContainer.classList.add('responses-container')

    const replyButton = document.createElement('button');
    replyButton.id = 'replyButton';

    const likeButton = document.createElement('button');
    likeButton.id = 'likeButton';

    const textContainer = document.createElement('div');
    textContainer.textContent = element.text;

    const actionContainer = document.createElement('div');

    replyButton.textContent = 'Reply'
    likeButton.textContent = `${element.likes > 0 ? `${element.likes} likes` : 'like'}`;

    replyButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      const newInput = inputContainer.cloneNode(true);
      newInput.value = '';
      newInput.focus();
      newInput.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
        handleEnter(e, element);
      })
      commentContainer.insertBefore(newInput, responsesContainer)
    })

    likeButton.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      element.likes++;
      likeButton.textContent = `${element.likes > 0 ? `${element.likes} likes` : 'like'}`;
    })

    //append
    commentContainer.appendChild(textContainer);
    commentContainer.appendChild(actionContainer)
    actionContainer.appendChild(likeButton)
    actionContainer.appendChild(replyButton)

    commentContainer.appendChild(responsesContainer);

    if (element.responses.length > 0) {
      renderComments(element.responses, responsesContainer);
    }

    parent.appendChild(commentContainer);

  });
}
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YfaiDc585Eo&list=PLf3gIiyzQm7MPxvhCzHTgQaArRPyOjjPT&index=7&t=13373s
En este enlace muestro el video en el que se basa.
3:29:00 es exacto donde empieza el codigo, si es que les sirve para entender el contexto.

Comment: Te falta el HTML. Agrégalo así es más fácil probarlo.

Comment: Tengo hecho el HTML, capaz no me explico bien...